# How do you summarize a list of 100 list of terms into a small number (~5) significant terms?

Tags: python, text, nlp

I have a list that has 100 terms that looks like this:

```
['Paycheck', 'Unemployment claim', 'credit card', 'minimum wage job', 'Instagram', 'xxx I hate you', 'u r sexy',....'hi Mr Robinson', 'savings', 'severance pay', 'deductible', 'rent forgiveness']
```

I want to ideally summarize this into a short list of 5~6 relevant terms, e.g.:

```
['Pay','Financial issues','unemployment','social benefits','money problems']
```

If that's too much, at least rank the terms by relevance and then list the top 5 terms.
Problem is most text analysis tools use term frequency and or work across multiple documents, but in my case, my list has only unique terms, and also contains noise (unrelated terms).

Is there any Python tool or API that can pull this off?

---

To clarify what I mean about relevance, consider the following simple example:

```
['Dollars','Cash','International Currency','Credit card','Comics','loans','David Beckham']
```

Most of the terms are related to money or finance, so `'Comics'` and `'David Beckham'` are irrelevant and needed to be discarded or placed at the lowest rank or something.

Then either provide two 'summary' terms like `'money'` and `'finance'` or just rank words by how close they are to the common meaning.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is your algorithm for "relevant terms"? As you said, normally that's calculated using tf-idf or other tools/algorithms. How do you determine what is relevant in a single list? And what is it relevant to?

Comment: Will edit accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can try word embeddings such as word2vec or BERT that for each term it gives a vector to you and you can compare values of these vectors using cosine similarity and put most similar terms in one array.

for more information you can look at these codes:

https://chainer-colab-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebook/official_example/word2vec.html

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZQvuAVwA3IjybezQOXnrXMGAnMyZRuPU